# Sharepoint online document library permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document

I have a document library and granted read-only permissions. However, users are still able to use the "copy to" feature. I would like users to only strictly view and download documents. Is this possible?

Also, I have disabled all access request setting and the "share" button still shows in the document library. Is there a way to hide this button?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: If people can download the document, they can also upload it anywhere they have permission to, so denying "copy to" really wouldn't accomplish much. Likewise they can screen shot anything that appears on their screen. Bottom line, if people can see the data, then they can see the data.

Comment: I agree with your point but for administrative purposes, it would be nice if we can block that. One of the members accidentally duplicated 2 copies of the files to different locations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting them to "Read Only" give them "View Only" permission.

Comment: I dont seem to have a "View Only" option. the options available are Full Control, Design, Edit, Contribute, Read, Approve, Manage Hierarchy, Restricted Read (will be testing this but it seems that they wont be able to download), and Restricted Interfaces for Translation

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible that users can only download files but cannot copy files. In the permission level, the "open items" permission make users can both download and copy documents. You cannot block "copy to" feature individually.

For the "share button", the Share button will still be shown even when sharing is disabled.
You could find answer here: 
[How do I disable "Get a Link" & "Share"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208090/how-do-i-disable-get-a-link-share)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Please accept if it helped you.