# Share a directory without giving delegation

Tags: sharepoint-online, share, directory

I want to share a directory to several users in write mode.

No problem to do it.

I want also that the users who have an access to the directory, **can't share the directory to others users**.

Is-it possible ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? Is it SharePoint Online? Or are you suggesting directories on local drive?

Comment: It is SharePoint Online. Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the sharing settings in this site via *Site permissions > Site Sharing > Change how members can share*.

Select "*Only site owners can share files, folders, and the site*" and also turn off "*Allow access requests*".

This will limit the sharing link options to only "*People with existing access*", so that no other user can be granted access to the directory by site users.

[image]

See the references here: [How do I disable “Get a Link” & “Share”.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208090/how-do-i-disable-get-a-link-share) /
[Manage sharing settings.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off)